# QProcess and shell : Destroyed while process is still running

Tags: qt, shell, qt-creator, sh, qprocess

I want to launch a shell script with Qt.

```
QProcess process;
process.start(commandLine, QStringList() << confFile);
process.waitForFinished();

if(process.exitCode()!=0)
{
    qDebug () << " Error " << process.exitCode() << process.readAllStrandardError();
}
else
{
    qDebug () << " Ok " << process.readAllStrandardOutput() << process.readAllStrandardError();
}
```

The result is :

> Ok : Result.... " "" QProcess : Destroyed while process is still
>   running.

This message does not appear every time.

What is the problem?

Comment: waitForFinished() has a timeout of 30 seconds and returns whether the waiting timed out or not. So check the waitForFinished() return value to check if the process actually quit.

Comment: @FrankOsterfeld that's an answer. And I can add use `waitForFinished ( -1)` if you really want to wait for the process to finish.

Comment: you miss typed readAllStandard. It is written as Strandard, this is not the issue, but confusing if someone would compile.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

`process.waitForFinished();` is hitting the default 30 seconds timeout. Use `process.waitForFinished(-1);` instead. This will make sure you wait for however long it takes for the process to finish, without any timeout.

Answer (score 4):

Note you create QProcess into the local scope. This means that the object will be deleted when you exit the scope. In the destructor QProcess process terminates. The message "Destroyed" while "the process is still running" when the process terminates in the destructor.

For solving this problem, you should call QProcess destructor when process is already terminated.

If will be QProcess::waitForFinished(-1) into your example, it will occur, but this will block you application.