# Properly using Qt QProcess

Tags: qt, qprocess

I'm considering to use QProcess to call a command line app ([gpio](http://wiringpi.com/the-gpio-utility/)) multiple times. Every time user clicks a button then a command is issued.

And the app output will be monitored and redirected to screeen. The code looks like the following.

```
void Gpio::command(QString argument)
{
//    if(process)
//        delete process;
    process = new QProcess(this);
    connect(process, SIGNAL(started()), this, SLOT(onStart()));
    connect(process, SIGNAL(finished(int,QProcess::ExitStatus)), this, SLOT(onFinish(int,QProcess::ExitStatus)));
    connect(process, SIGNAL(readyReadStandardOutput()), this, SLOT(readGpio()));
    QString program("gpio");
    QStringList list = argument.split(" ");
    process->start(program, list);
}
```

Question: Should I `delete process`? Doing so I got:

```
QProcess: Destroyed while process is still running.
```

Monitoring `exitCode` and `exitStatus` I see they are always `0`.

This question concerns more about the proper use of QProcess while ["QProcess and shell : Destroyed while process is still running"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14504201/qprocess-and-shell-destroyed-while-process-is-still-running) focus on the specific error.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [QProcess and shell : Destroyed while process is still running](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14504201/qprocess-and-shell-destroyed-while-process-is-still-running)

Comment: do you need to run multiple processes i.e., is user allowed to click the button multiple times? or, a single process but different args every time?

Comment: Different args every time.

Answer (score 1):

as you don't want to run multiple processes concurrently (as per the comments), you don't need to create / delete the `QProcess` multiple times.

gpio.h

```
QProcess*   m_gpioProcess;
```

gpio.cpp file

```
Gpio::Gpio(.....),
   .....(),
   m_gpioProcess(new QProcess(this))
{
   m_gpioProcess->setProgram("gpio");

   connect(m_gpioProcess, SIGNAL(started()), this, SLOT(onStart()));
   connect(m_gpioProcess, SIGNAL(finished(int,QProcess::ExitStatus)), this, SLOT(onFinish(int,QProcess::ExitStatus)));
   connect(m_gpioProcess, SIGNAL(readyReadStandardOutput()), this, SLOT(readGpio()));
}

void Gpio::command(const QString& args)
{
  if (m_gpioProcess->state() != QProcess::NotRunning) {
    qDebug() << "Process already running, ignoring the request";
    return;
  }

  m_gpioProcess->setArguments(args.split(" "));
  m_gpioProcess->start();
  if (m_gpioProcess->waitForStarted()) {
    qDebug() << "Process started with arguments:" << m_gpioProcess->arguments();
  }
}
```

if you want to prevent user clicking the button multiple times, consider enabling / disabling the button as per `m_gpioProcess` state.

---

for `Qt` 4.8, just remove this line

```
m_gpioProcess->setProgram("gpio");
```

and this line

```
m_gpioProcess->setArguments(args.split(" "));
```

and change this line

```
m_gpioProcess->start();
```

to

```
m_gpioProcess->start("gpio", args.split(" "));
```

Comment: I think this is directed to Qt5, I'm on Qt4. Can't see `setProgram` and `setArguments` in Qt4. Is there any way around?

Comment: So I got `QProcess::start: Process is already running`. I don't want to ignore the request. How long should I wait to shoot a new command (each command returns almost immediately)?

Comment: you have the `finished(int,QProcess::ExitStatus)` signal to monitor this. You should be able to create new command right after this.

Comment: You mean after `exitCode=0` and `exitStatus=0` I should be able to call `start` again (with different args)? I'm doing that and getting `QProcess::start: Process is already running`. Perhaps something must be done between this two steps?

Comment: May ask what happens after finished is emitted that prevents the object to be deleted? I guess the same thing that prevents me to start again also prevents me to delete the object.

Comment: remember, `process->waitForFinished()` will freeze your app until it returns. make sure that your command is actually finishing quite fast.

Answer (score 0):

Well, It seems I was forgetting `process->waitForFinished();` after the call to `start`. This seems to solve the problem.

Answer (score -1):

add following code maybe helpful:

```
process->close();
```

Comment: Could you add more of an explanation? What does this code do? Where do you add this line of code?